# Order by the result of a division of two counts

Tags: sql

I have a query like this one:

```
SELECT
  type,
  count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
  count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
  count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL

FROM
  table

GROUP BY
  type
```

I want to order the results so the rows with the type with the highest percentage of passed is on top.

I though something like:

```
ORDER BY
  "PASSED"/"TOTAL" DESC
```

But it's not working.

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You are ordering by strings there,remove the quotes.

Comment: @Mihai - ANSI standard is that quotes delimit identifiers rather than strings.

Comment: But if he's using MySQL, I don't think it follows that part of the standard, I think it will interpret that as strings.

Comment: So mysql is the retarded cousin in the sql family?

Comment: It uses backticks to delimit identifiers, so you can use both single and double quotes to delimit strings.

Comment: @Barmar - This depends on `ANSI_QUOTES` mode AFAIK. SQL Server has a similar setting `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` (that defaults to on)

Comment: Didn't know about that option, but I assume it defaults to off, and most installations leave it like this. Similar to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT
  type,
  count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
  count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
  count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL

FROM
  table

GROUP BY
  type
ORDER BY 
  count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end)/count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) desc
```

But this can produce `division by zero` exception you have to check if count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) is not zero.

The other solution is using sub-queries - You enclose your initial query in sub-query and then you can order, limit or filter this sub-query as simple table in SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
      type,
      count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
      count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
      count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL

    FROM
      table

    GROUP BY
      type
) AS SUB_DATA
ORDER BY PASSED/TOTAL DESC
```

if you are using PostgreSQL you can use `WITH` construction (I very like it).

```
WITH _records as (
    SELECT
      type,
      count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
      count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
      count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL

    FROM
      table

    GROUP BY
      type
)
SELECT * 
FROM _records
ORDER BY PASSED/TOTAL DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

If Column aliases that are defined in the `SELECT` are then referenced in the `ORDER BY` they must be used on their own. Not in an expression.

You can use a derived table.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
/* Your Query here*/
) T
ORDER BY PASSED/TOTAL DESC
```

You may also need to cast `PASSED` to numeric to avoid integer division depending on your DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (PASSED / TOTAL) [percent] FROM
(   SELECT
      type,
      count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
      count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
      count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
      count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL

    FROM
      table

    GROUP BY
      type ) T
ORDER BY [percent]
```

Answer (score 1):

your code works in sql server, but not in oracle i think. try:

```
SELECT
  type,
  count(case when STATUS = 'N/A' then 1 end) as NOTAPPLICABLE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Failed' then 1 end) as FAILED,
  count(case when STATUS = 'No Run' then 1 end) as NO_RUN,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Not Completed' then 1 end) as NOT_COMPLETE,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Blocked' then 1 end) as Blocked,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) as PASSED,
  count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as TOTAL,
  count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) / count(case when STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end) as sort
FROM
  table

GROUP BY
  type
ORDER BY 9
  sort DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. As others already pointed out, you cant' use column aliases in
   calculation. Instead of `ORDER BY PASSED/TOTAL DESC`, write `ORDER
   BY count(case when STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 end) / count(case when
   STATUS <> 'N/A' then 1 end)`
2. If you divide PASSED by TOTAL, and PASSED is less than TOTAL, you'll
   always get 0 as a result. Just like `select 5/10` will return 0
   instead of 0.5 - because both values are integers, you'll get integer as a result. `select 1.0*5/10` will return 0.5